# How to navigate from one view to another view from a menubar of website in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-2

I have a simple static website. I am using codeigniter framework for learning purpose and also have a login and upload images section in the website. As of now , I am unable to link the pages in the website using the menubar of the website. I know I have to link different views. Could anyone please help me how to do it.? Please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't link to views.  URLs are mapped to controllers, which process input and load views.  Here is a simple example:

*application/controllers/welcome.php:*

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    // mapped to http://example.com/welcome
    public function index()
    {
        // load welcome view
        $this->load->view('welcome');
    }

}
```

*application/views/welcome.php:*

```
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<p>Click <a href="/contact">here</a> to view the contact form.</p>
```

*application/controllers/contact.php:*

```
class Contact extends CI_Controller {

    // mapped to http://example.com/contact
    public function index()
    {
        // load contact view
        // ...
    }

}
```

When `http://example.com/welcome` is requested, CodeIgniter calls the `index()` method of the `Welcome` controller which loads the `welcome.php` view.  In the `welcome.php` view there is a link to the `Contact` controller which loads contact-related views.  So as you can see, we are not linking directly to views.  We are linking to controllers which in turn load views.

It seems like you don't have too good of a grasp of MVC.  I would recommend you read or reread the [CodeIgniter user guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/index.html) and pay specific attention to the sections on [controllers](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html), [views](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html), and [CodeIgniter URLs](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html).